# R DataExplorer package - Cannot use functions

Tags: r, package

I successfully installed [boxuancui's `DataExplorer` package](https://github.com/boxuancui/DataExplorer) in R, but when I go to use functions from this package, I'm getting errors.

> Error: could not find function "plot_missing"
>   Error: could not find function "create_report"

I downloaded from GitHub:

```
if (!require(remotes)) install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("boxuancui/DataExplorer")
```

Any suggestions as to why?

Below are my particulars.

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.2                         
year           2016                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        71607                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch
```

Comment: [Cross posted on GitHub](https://github.com/boxuancui/DataExplorer/issues/79)...

Comment: Have you loaded the package?

Comment: @PoGibas yes I have loaded the package